# Can add_image_size be added earlier

Tags: hooks, actions

I need to read some theme options before `add_image_size` is executed so I changed the action priority to 9 instead of the default 10

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', '_my_action_add_image_sizes',9 );
```

do you think there would be some issues with this ?

Comment: You don't really show enough code to answer well.  Can't `_my_action_add_image_sizes` just read the options and then call `add_image_size` after ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the priority to 999 to make sure if you are going that way:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', '_my_action_add_image_sizes', 999 );
```

but if you really want to make sure of that order, try making a `custom action`, here a small example:

```
/**
 * Execute the action with do_action.
 */
 function read_theme_options() {
   //all the logic you want to execute before adding image sizes here

   do_action( 'my_action' );//do the action
 }

 /**
  * Register the action, you can add the functions you want to the action
  */
  add_action( 'my_action', '_my_action_add_image_sizes' );
  function _my_action_add_image_sizes() {
    //adding images here
  }
```